# Is golang have operator like 'as'(C#)

Tags: go, testing

Code logic as Below:

```
func (c *Auth) ensureCredential() (azcore, error) {
    _, err = c.build(authData)
}

func (c *Auth) build(authData []byte) (*Client, error) {
return NewClient()
}
```

The C# code I want to copy

```
public async Task test()
{
            var auth = new Auth();
            var inner = await _cre(auth);

            // This part code I want to copy 
            Client client = inner as Client
            Assert some values equals Client's fileds
}

public async Task<azcore> _credential(Auth provider)
{
            await provider.EnsureCredential(IsAsync, default);
            return (azcore)typeof(Auth).GetField("_cre", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(provider);
}
```

Both type `Auth` and `Client` implement interface `azcore`.
I want to let `Auth` **as** `Client` so that test some values in `Auth` whether equals `Client`'s field.
Those values in  `Auth` would assign to `Client`'s fields according my code logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps type assertion (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions). But your question is unclear. Can you write a sample in C# to give a clearer picture

Comment: @W.K.S thanks for your help on this, I update the C# code in question.

Comment: Huh? Both `Auth` and `Client` implement interface `X`, therefore C# can cast one to another? That makes no sense to me. You can only cast up an inheritance tree, or to an interface. So `Auth as X` or `Client as X`. If you can do `Auth as Client` then perhaps `Client` is a base class for `Auth`?

Comment: Does your C# code work? Perhaps what you mean is that you pass an instance of `Auth` to the `_credentials` function and it returns an instance of `Client`?

Answer (score 0):

In Go interfaces are implemented implicitly.

You can define an interface with the getters needed to retrive the values you want to compare.

```golang
type Azcore interface {
    SomeValue() int         // This is a getter
    SomeOtherValue() string // This is a getter
}
```

Then you can declare these methods on the Client type

```golang
type Client struct {
    Value      int
    OtherValue string
    ExtraValue float64
}

func (c *Client) SomeValue() int {
    return c.Value
}

func (c *Client) SomeOtherValue() string {
    return c.OtherValue
}
```

and finally declare the "same" methods for Auth type

```golang
type Auth struct {
    Value        int
    SpecialValue string
}

func (a *Auth) SomeValue() int {
    return a.Value
}

func (a *Auth) SomeOtherValue() string {
    return a.SpecialValue
}
```

You can then use the `Azcore` type in functions, as parameter or as result of a conversion

```golang
func areEquals(a, b Azcore) bool {
    return a.SomeValue() == b.SomeValue() && a.SomeOtherValue() == b.SomeOtherValue()
}

func (a *Auth) AsAzcore() Azcore {
    return a
}

func (c *Client) AsAzcore() Azcore {
    return c
}
```

Check it in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pViI9VSZZtH)